# SQL query to get the output

Tags: sql, oracle, join, hiveql

I have two tables Table A and Table B as listed below.

```
Table A 
--------
X
Y

Table 
--------
X
Y
```

What is the SQL query to get the below output?

```
XX
XY
YX
YY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a `cross join`, to generate all possible combinations of rows between the two tables. Assuming a structure like `tablea(col)`, `tableb(col)`:

```
select a.col, b.col
from tablea a 
cross join tableb b
order by a.col, b.col
```

If you want to concatenate the results in a singe column:

```
select a.col || b.col as col
from tablea a 
cross join tableb b
order by a.col, b.col
```

Comment: Thank You for the response. Is there any other way to achieve the output without using cross/cartesian joins, since cartesian joins are generally not preferred,

Comment: @SNS: what you ask for is a cartesian product in essence, so this is how to do it...

Comment: Thank You. I'll try the query out to see the output